# Why is my $(selector).index(filter selector) returning an incorrect result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, filtering

I have a variable `pages`

```
pages = $("[data-role=page]:not([data-url])");
```

which is

```
[
<div data-role=​"page" id=​"home" class=​"home ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex=​"0" style=​"min-height:​ 548px;​">​…​</div>​
, 
<div data-role=​"page" id=​"login" class=​"login ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" tabindex=​"0" style>​…​</div>​
]
```

But when I use `pages.index(".ui-page-active")` I get `-1` — an incorrect result.

However, when I search for `pages.index(".ui-page")` I get `1` — the proper result.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

`pages.index( $('.ui-page-active') )` returns `1` — the proper result! But why isn't [the selector option](http://api.jquery.com/index/) working?

Comment: Please create a minimal jsfiddle test-case - e.g. can this be reproduced on a normal browser *without* jquery mobile?

Comment: i think you want `$('.ui-page-active').index(pages)`

Comment: It's not working as you expect because that's not how it is documented to work. It doesn't find the index of elements in teh current collection that match the selector, it finds the index of the first element in the collection in the elements that are matched BY the passed in selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.index()` method takes the first element of your current selection and searches for it amongst all elements from the selector you pass. **[See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)**

**[It may help to look at the responsible code](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/index/)**

So when I do:

```
$('.a').index('.b');
```

It will give you the index of the very first `.a` element within all found `.b` elements.

It seems what you want is the opposite of what you have, so possibly:

```
// Find '.ui-page' within the '[data-role=page]:not([data-url])' set:
$('.ui-page').index('[data-role=page]:not([data-url])');
```

But note that this'll only look for the very first `.ui-page` element in the elements that match the selector you passed to `index(...)`.